# How to infinite loop every video I play as defaut on MPV player without having to press shift+L hotkey every single time?

Tags: media-player, mplayer, infinite-loop, mpv

I think the title is clear without filling the body.

Every time I play new video the inf loop is gone and I need to press shift+L again each time. How to just make this my default setting. As far as I know there is no configuration in this program. Sorry if I'm wrong or haven't looked hard enough.

Answer (score 19):

> As far as I know there is no configuration in this program.

While it isn't created by default, `mpv` supports a file called `mpv.conf`, which allows `mpv` behavior to be customized (globally, for particular media extensions, or by setting other custom "profiles" that refer to an arbitrary group of options and that can be used with `--profile=`). An overview of the general format of `mpv.conf` for the most recent versions of `mpv` can be found [here](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#configuration-files) ("Stable" version [here](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#configuration-files)).

> How do I infinitely loop every video I play by defaut with MPV player?

1. Create a text file called `mpv.conf`.
2. Place the following line in that file:

   *ex. mpv.conf*

   ```
   loop-file=inf
   ```
3. Place `mpv.conf` under one of the following directories (depending on your platform):

   ```
   # Linux

   # System-wide
   /etc/mpv
   /usr/local/etc/mpv

   # User specific
   ~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf

   # Windows
   C:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\mpv\mpv.conf

   # Create "portable_config" in the same folder as mpv.exe
   C:\path\to\mpv\portable_config\mpv.conf
   ```

If you want to infinitely loop a playlist, use `loop-playlist=inf`. You can add both options to `mpv.conf` to create an infinite playlist where each entry loops infinitely as well:

*ex. mpv.conf*

```
loop-playlist=inf
loop-file=inf
```

For usability, you can also add a profile to disable looping:

*ex. mpv.conf*

```
# global (default) options
loop-playlist=inf
loop-file=inf

# "finite" playback profile (disable looping)
# usage: mpv --profile=finite ...
# Note that "finite" is an arbitrary name
[finite]
loop-playlist=no
loop-file=no
```

---

**References (mpv)**

- *[loop-file](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-loop-file)*
- *[loop-playlist](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-loop-playlist)*

Answer (score 8):

You could make alias with loop option and save it to .profile or .zshrc or .bashrc like:

```bsh
alias mpvl='mpv --loop '
```